# webservice won't build - "Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'"

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, linq-to-sql, asmx

I am using a web service and trying to return the result string by entering an int but it is returning a format error.

error: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'"

here is the code which i am using:

```
[WebMethod]
public int prop_name(int id)
{
    using(DataClassesDataContext context=new DataClassesDataContext())
    {
        var name = (from a in context.Property_details where a.prop_id == id select a.prop_title).FirstOrDefault();
        return name; <----'name' is underlined red
    }
}
```

Comment: Change `public int` to `public string`.

Comment: but the id is in int format

Comment: are you familiar with Method signature / return types.. you have to have the same datatype in your return or Cast/Convert it have you debugged that code.. if not ..do so and you will see what the value of name is.. if worse comes to worse hover over var section where you have var name...and it will tell you the type implicitly

Comment: You are selecting a `prop_title` which sounds like a string. So `name` is a string (even if you may know that there should only be digits in there). You can't return a string from a method that's declared to return an int.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try `return Convert.ToInt32(name);`

Comment: Then you should follow Rick S's suggestion and change the method to return a string.  The data returned into the name variable is obviously not an integer if you are getting that error.